# how to restrict form submission in drupal form api using PHP

Tags: drupal-forms

I have a drupal form, and i want to display and error message based on checking a condition, which in-turn should restrict the form submission, when the error message is displayed.

I was able to do this in Javascript, but seeking how to implement it using PHP.

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance
Vivek R

Answer (score 0):

use hook_validate() and write your validations similar to Javascript..